# Django pass data from HTML table to database model

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, django-models

I am creating a student attendance system using django. I am fetching all student's names from the student database into an HTML table and updating information about students to django model.

This is my view.py to get data

```
def attendanceFill (request, subject):
    context = ''
    ad_standard = request.session.get('standardO')
    subjects = CustomStudent.objects.filter(className__name__contains = ad_standard, subjectName__subjects__contains = subject)
    # attendanceForm = Attendance(request.POST or None, instance=subjects)
    print(ad_standard)
    print(subject)
    print(subjects)
    context = {'subjects' : subjects}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student = request.POST
        print(student)
    return render(request, 'teacher/attendance_fill.html', context)
```

This is my HTML template for data handling.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class= "row mt-4">            
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                    {% for student in subjects %}
                    <tr>
                        <td name= 'student'><p class="student-name" id="student-name">{{ student.sname }}</p></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="attendance" id="attendance">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" name="checked" id = "checked" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4 shadow" style="border-radius:25px;">Submit</button>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>                      
                </table>
            </form>
            
        </div>
</div>
```

This is jquery function I am using to capture data.

```
var formData = new FormData()
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#checked").click('click', function(){
                $students = document.getElementsByClassName('student-name').textContent;
                $attendance = $('#attendance').val()

                console.log($students)
                console.log($attendance)
            })
        })
```

I have tried `$('student-name').val()` to get value for all students but it returns blank. Nothing is captured with this method.
I wish capture all data and update it into attendance model.

This are my models:

```
    # Custom Student Table
    class CustomStudent(models.Model):
        _id = models.AutoField
        sname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        slname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        admissionNo = models.CharField(default= "", max_length=50)
        parentName = models.CharField(default= "", max_length=100)
        emerContact = models.CharField(default= "", max_length=50)
        contactNo = models.CharField(default= "", max_length=50)
        className = models.ForeignKey(Standard, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        subjectName = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
        Year = models.CharField(default="", max_length=5)
        email = models.CharField(default="", max_length=60)
        address = models.CharField(default="", max_length=250)
    
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            # return str(self.slname)
            return str(self.sname)
    
    
       
            
    AttendenceChioces = [
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    ]
    
    # Student Attendance Table
    cla

 AttendanceStudent(models.Model):
    attendace_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(CustomStudent, on_delete=CASCADE)
    attendace = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices=AttendenceChioces)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now= True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sname)
```

Is there any other efficient way to submit attendance data into database. I have tried capturing all data using jquery but it returns blank.

**UPDATE**:
I have figured out proper way to send data but issue is django is not receiving any data in view funtion. I have created a view function to process data as my current view function `attendancefill` cannot process url without `subject` value.

```
def attendanceFilled(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print (request.POST)
        return JsonResponse({'data' : request.POST}, status=200)

    return render(request, 'teacher/attendance_st.html')
```

I have verified via console.log and chrome DevTools tat ajax is sending data. But in django there is no data. I have tried printing new data at all points in new view function. It always returns a empty dict.

This is my updated jquery:

```
var value = []
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            $("#checked").click('click', function(){
                csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
                value.push({'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : '{{ csrf_token }}'})
                $('#attendance_table tr').each(function(a,b){
                    $student = $('.student-name', b).text();
                    $present = $('#attendance', b).prop('checked');
                    value.push({Student : $student, Present : $present})

                })
                
                var datatoadd = JSON.stringify(value);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = datatoadd;
                console.log(datatoadd)

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '{% url "attendanceFilled" %}',
                    data: datatoadd,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(){
                        alert('Attendance submitted')
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
                        console.log(xhr.status + ":" + xhr.responseText)
                        alert('Attendance Failed to Submit! Please contact adminitstrator with your issue!')
                    } 
                })
            })
        })
```

my path in urls:

```
path('subject/<slug:subject>/', views.attendanceFill, name="subject"),
path('attendanceFilled', views.attendanceFilled, name="attendanceFilled"),
```

I am only posting required URLs here my URL file is too big.

Answer (score 1):

@Sahil Mohile- Your model needs some clean-up.

```
class StudentAttendance(models.Model):
    attendance_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(CustomStudent, on_delete=CASCADE,db_index=True)
    attendace = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=AttendenceChioces) 
    date = models.DateField(auto_now= True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)#Dont call it #tname, explicit is better than implicit. 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sname)
```

Now. my main point. Attendance record is tied to a Term/Semester. How about you
create a Semester Table. Tie the student attendance with a specific semester/term

```
import datetime
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db import models


def current_year():
    return datetime.date.today().year


def max_value_current_year(value):
    return MaxValueValidator(current_year())(value)


  class Semester(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        year = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=current_year(), validators=[MinValueValidator(1984), max_value_current_year])
        .........
   e.g Fall 2020



 class StudentAttendance(models.Model):
        attendance_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
        semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester,db_index=True)
        student = models.ForeignKey(CustomStudent, on_delete=CASCADE,db_index=True)
        attendace = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=AttendenceChioces) 
        date = models.DateField(auto_now= True)
        teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)#Dont call it #tname, explicit is better than implicit.
```

Also, I predict that there might be a situation where you will be asked to present the number of present days for a specific student in a specific semester. Something to think about.

---

I am a bit confused. You are capturing the data but where are you making the ajax POST? You need to share the POST request

```
var formData = new FormData()
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#checked").click('click', function(){
                $students = document.getElementsByClassName('student-name').textContent;
                $attendance = $('#attendance').val()

                console.log($students)
                console.log($attendance)
            })
        })
```

Shouldn't you be doing the following too

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'your url',
            data: {
                 #your data
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token
            },     
           success:function(response){
          },
          error:function(error){
            }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will work on making semesters a point. `tname` is a field which holds teacher value. Eg. Name of teacher who took attendance.

Comment: @SDRJ- Thanks for suggestion i have updated my database. Also I have updated my question to new point out issue clearly. It would be great if you can provide little more support for issue

Comment: I have updated my answer with jquery. Sorry for confusing update.

Comment: @SahilMohile- what does request.POST display in your logs?

Comment: @SahilMohile-Add this if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":

Comment: @SDRJ- I added all values but it still give empty dict.

Comment: @SahilMohile- Are you sure the data is actually passed by the ajax call?

Comment: @SDRJ- Yes, I have confirmed twice by printing variable in before ajax call and I have also checked in Devtools. Under Networking >> Headers. It appears under request payloads

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing json.loads(request.POST) since you are stringfying the data while sending it in your POST request?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that it shows different error as QueryDict object has no attribute read. Also Can we move this to chat as this many comments may cause issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229122/discussion-between-sdrj-and-sahil-mohile).